# Need C# regexp for URL validation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How to validate by a single regular expression the urls:

```
http://83.222.4.42:8880/listen.pls
http://www.my_site.com/listen.pls
http://www.my.site.com/listen.pls
```

to be true?

I see that I formulated the question not exactly :(, sorry my mistake. The idea is that I want to validate with the help of regexp valid urls, let it be an external ip address or the domain name. This is the idea, other valid urls can be considered:

```
http://93.122.34.342/
http://193.122.34.342/abc/1.html
http://www.my_site.com/listen2.pls
http://www.my.site.com/listen.php
```

and so on.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "C# regexp"; a regular expression is a regular expression, right? And to get the answer you want/need, it might be a good idea to specify your question more completely.

Comment: We need to know more about what patterns you want to match. 3 examples isn't enough.  Describe it.

Comment: there are many slightly different flavours of regexp so specifying c# is a good idea

Comment: @jk: the pedant in me says to specifiy ".NET Regex".

Comment: @diadiora you edited to provide more examples, but I still don't think you've povided enough information. What are the patterns you need to match / reject?

Answer (score 7):

**The road to hell is paved with string parsing.**

URL parsing in particular is the source of many, many exploited security issues. Don't do it.

For example, do you want this to match?

Note the uppercase scheme section.  Remember that some parts of a URL are case sensitive, and some are not. Then there's encoding rules. Etc.

Start by using `System.Uri` to parse the URLs you provide:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://83.222.4.42:8880/listen.pls");
```

Then you can write things like:

```
if (uri.Scheme == "http" &&
    uri.Host == "83.222.4.42" &&
    uri.AbsolutePath == "/listen.pls"
    )
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean any URL ending with `/listen.pls`? In that case try this:

```
^http://[^/]+/listen\.pls$
```

or if the protocol identifier must be optional:

```
^[http://]?[^/]+/listen\.pls$
```

Anyway take a look here, maybe it is useful for you: [Url and Email validation using Regex](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=586)

Comment: Does not work if the URL contains directories. Contains typo ".ps" -> ".pls".

Comment: Not exactly, I reformulated the question, see what I had edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^http:\/\/[-_a-zA-Z0-9.]+(:\d+)?\/listen\.pls$/
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, sorry my mistake, I reformulated the question, see what I had edited.

Answer (score 1):

^http://.+/listen\.pls$

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer? While short answers may help by pointing in the right direction, it would be helpful to have further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If there are strictly only 3 of them don't bother with a regular expression because **there is not necessarily a good pattern match when everything is already strictly known** - in fact you might accidentally match more than these three urls - which becomes a problem if the urls are intended for security purposes or something equally important. Instead, test the three cases directly - maybe put them in a configuration file.

In the future if you want to add more URLs to the list you'll likely end up with an overly complicated regular expression that's increasingly hard to maintain and takes the place of a simpler check against a small list.

You won't necessarily get speed gains by running Regex to find these three strings - in fact it might be quite expensive.

*Note:* If you wantUri regular expressions also try websites hosting libraries like [Regex Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=http&c=2&m=-1&ps=20) - there are many to pick and choose from if your needs change.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version base upon [Jay Bazuzi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905852/need-c-regexp-for-url-validation/1906073#1906073) above since I can't post code in comment, it checks a blacklisted extensions (I do this only for demonstration purpose, you should strongly consider to build a whitelist rather than a blacklist) :

```
string myurl = "http://www.my_site.com/listen.pls";
Uri myUri = new Uri(myurl);
string[] invalidExtensions = {
    ".pls",
    ".abc"
};

foreach(string invalidExtension in invalidExtensions) {
    if (invalidExtension.ToLower().Equals(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myUri.AbsolutePath))) {
        //Logic here
    }

}
```